# Can inserting/removing one point in a quadtree or octree cause multiple splits/collapses?

Tags: 2d, octree, quadtree, spatial-partitioning

I was reading Robert Nystrom's Game Programming Patterns website and, in the section about spatial partitioning, particularly in the section on quadtrees, he mentions:

> Objects can be added incrementally. Adding a new object means finding the right square and adding it. If that bumps that square above the maximum count, it gets subdivided. The other objects in that square get pushed down into the new smaller squares. This requires a little work, but it’s a fixed amount of effort: the number of objects you have to move will always be less than the maximum object count. **Adding a single object can never trigger more than one subdivision.**
> Removing objects is equally simple. You remove the object from its square and if the parent square’s total count is now below the threshold, you can collapse those subdivisions.

I can't help but wonder if this is really right. Experimenting with certain simulators [this one](https://google.github.io/closure-library/source/closure/goog/demos/quadtree.html), when adding a point that is close to another one (and since it only allows one point per grid space) multiple subdivisions happen until they're fit. The same happens when you remove a point, with the subdivisions collapsing.

An example using the website:

[image: one point]

With just another point, 5 subdivisions happen:

[image: two points]

Was this perhaps a mistake on Nystrom's part? Or is it just a definition that can change from quadtree implementation to implementation? I'm also wondering if the same can happen with octrees.

Comment: It looks to me like your example answers the question.

Comment: I mean, that's why I'm asking if it could be an implementation detail that can be chosen @DMGregory. I'm not well versed enough in this to know if every implementation must behave the same as the one in the simulator I linked.